# GlassFish Server still showing as "Running" when I open http://localhost:8080/ but server status in NetBeans shows that server is not running

Tags: java, glassfish-4, netbeans-7.4

While working on NetBeans I am using GlassFish 4.0. The server is not running through NetBeans, as in it has not been started and yet http:// localhost : 8080/ shows that the server is running.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you can access the server it must be running. Do you still see it in Task Manager?

Answer (score 0):

try to clear your Browser cache, I was having the same issue but was just the browser cache, I opened a new incognito window and the server page was gone.

Comment: Try to refesh with CTRL + F5